# Webview cookies from react native application

Tags: react-native, security, cookies, webview

in my React native app after logging in the session got stored in the cookies and I can request any secured data from the backend easily but at a specific screen in the app I'm using a webview, now the problem is :
I want to trigger a secure API call from my webview. I always get 401 as unauthorized because in the instance of the browser that the web view is using we're not setting any cookies and you can't set cookies manually because it's not secure. Obviously, I don't want to redirect the user to the auth screen again.
now I have the value of my session, how can I use it to trigger a secure call from my webview?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a cookie in a custom header, something like this:

```
<WebView
  source={{
    ...
    headers: {
      Cookie: 'cookie',
    },
  }}
  sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
/>
```

See [Managing Cookies](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#managing-cookies) for details.

Comment: I actually tried implementing this solution but it didn't work, after inspecting the webview in chrome:\\inspect I found out the the cookies were not set, there are only the original cookies that came with the original site